# How to create a new column from the data received using sum(1) on that row in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query where I m getting the count of that row but I m trying to receive count based on two conditions but the output that I get is in one single row for both the conditions.I want to get another new Column for the second condition similar to how I get for my first condition.My Query is below

```
SELECT 
    SUM(1) AS Usercount, feild
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code) AS feild
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        type = 'Usercount' and code = 001
            AND locId IN (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                location
            WHERE
                id IN (1) AND status = 1)
    GROUP BY id) AS deptdata
    WHERE
        feild NOT LIKE '%,%') AS Data
GROUP BY feild 
UNION SELECT 
    SUM(1) AS EmployeeCount, feild
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code) AS feild
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        type = 'EmployeeCount' and code = 001
            AND locId IN (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                location
            WHERE
                id IN (1) AND status = 1)
    GROUP BY id) AS deptdata
    WHERE
        feild NOT LIKE '%,%') AS Data
GROUP BY feild
```

After excecuting this I get two columns first column is for UserCount and second column is for code .That is

```
Usercount Code
3         001
```

But I want the Output as

```
UserCount EmployeeCount  Code
3              2          001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below way - using conditional aggregation

```
select feild,
       count(case when type='Usecount' then 1 end) as UserCount,
       count(case when type='EmployeeCount' then 1 end) as EmployeeCount
from
(
SELECT id,type,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code) AS feild
FROM table
    WHERE code = 001
            AND locId IN (SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                location
            WHERE
                id IN (1) AND status = 1)
GROUP BY id,type
)A where feild NOT LIKE '%,%' group by feild
```